# Error:R cannot be resolved - Android - A check list

Tags: android, reference

This would serve the purpose as a **check list**, when someone encounter this basic error on android.
Please add interesting points you have come across.
Refer links

**Description**: R.java is a generated class. In a Android Development Tools (ADT) environment it is generated whenever the project is built. This class holds all the references of your android project in integer values. whenever you reference a R. something that means you refer to one of this integer value.

**Cause:** This Error may happen when the R.java is not properly generated.

**Errors:** There are several reasons which prevent this R.java from generated automatically which will be detailed below by our fellows.

Thank you.

Comment: Clean your project and remove line import com.android.R if you have it. Also make sure you dont have errors in classes and XML files because R.java is not regenerated in this case.

Comment: check for errors in your resource files

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that AndroidBuildTools are installed and your views are correct.
Sometimes needs to import .R;